# Calling a function with a parameter that can belong to different classes

Tags: c#, interface

I have two classes that are slightly different in fields. Is it possible to implement a function that could accept objects of both one and the second class as a parameter. I tried to implement it using interfaces, but when designing classes, it gives an error -
"Class1Top" does not implement the interface member "interface Top.Property2". "Class1 Top.Property2"cannot implement "interfaceTop.Property2", because it does not have the corresponding return type "interfaceMiddle".

```
public interface interfaceTop {
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    interfaceMiddle Property2 { get; set; }
}
public interface interfaceMiddle {
    interfaceBottom Property1 { get; set; }
}
public interface interfaceBottom {
    int Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1Top :interfaceTop {
   public int Property1 { get; set; }
   public Class1Middle Property2 { get; set; }
}
public class Class1Middle : interfaceMiddle {
    public Class1Bottom Property1 { get; set; }
}
public class Class1Bottom : interfaceBottom {
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2Top :interfaceTop {
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public Class2Middle Property2 { get; set; }
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
public class Class2Middle : interfaceMiddle {
    public Class2Bottom Property1 { get; set; }
}
public class Class2Bottom: interfaceBottom {
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
// I need just such a check
public class result {
   public bool Result(interfaceTop obj) {
        return obj.Property2.Property1.Property1 == 1;
   }
}
```

How to implement such a possibility of transmission or the possibility of checking as a
result of
public bool (top interface object)

Comment: I assume, in Class2Top, Property2 should be of type Class2Middle?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics):

You can do a generic class , and you can set that the generic parameter implements any interface. Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-interfaces)

So your solution can be for example something like this:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T: interfaceBottom,interfaceMiddle,InterfaceTop {
    public bool (T object){
//here check the type ob the interface

    }
}
```